# Trying to remember the updated ajax html when user hitting back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make the browser to remeber the ajax updated html. So when user hit the back button, it will go back to the ajax update html. I had found the following code from stackoverflow, but I had no idea how to use it. I had tried to replace the #Mytable with my class .post-content. But it doesn't work, do I miss something. Help, appreciate.

```js
$('#pagination').click(function(e){
 
 var data = {
              action: 'post_pagination_ajax',
        AjaxFrontNonce : Child_ajax.ajaxLoadUserNonce,
    
    };
 $.ajax({
  url: ajax_front_gallery.ajaxurl,
  type:'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
  $('.post-content').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();
    $fa_spen.fadeOut();
  }
  });
    return false;  
});

 

// the following code found on stackoverflow, but I don't know how to replace it with my code.
 if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
     if ('myTable' in localStorage && window.location.hash) {
         $("#myTable").html(localStorage.getItem('myTable'));
     }
 }/*remember the previous div position*/

 // Replace the search result table on load.
 if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
     if ('myTable' in localStorage && window.location.hash) {
         $("#myTable").html(localStorage.getItem('myTable'));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just reload the previous page? Also, is the first part of that snippet your own try and the second part of the snippet what you've found? Have they no futher relation other than that they exist in the same script?

Comment: If I hit the go back button, it will not remember the ajax update html. This is the only snippet I found.